# How can I transfer my Azure bizspark Subscription to another person

Tags: azure, bizspark

I have an active BizSpark account and I want to transfer this to another person in my company. How can I do this?

I tried to transfer my account using the instructions in this Microsoft article 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-subscription-transfer/ but without success.

**Update**

In don't have the "Manage" option on my BizSpark account.

[image]

Comment: It seems that Bizspark accounts do have quite a special status within Azure (i.e. lots of things are a little different - read as 'lots of things don't quite work') However this question is off topic for Stackoverflow, because it is a question about subscriptions and will likely be closed. You would need to raise this with Azure Support (which you have as part of your subscription)

Comment: @MichaelB-AzureMVP I already open a ticket on Azure Support. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official FAQ:
https://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/faqs.aspx

"To reassign your BizSpark administrator privileges, you will first need to add a user to your BizSpark account... Once the invitation has been accepted and the new user has received their confirmation of enrollment"

See screenshot below for details:
[image: BizSpark FAQ]

Full text from FAQ screenshot:

> To reassign your BizSpark administrator privileges, you will first
>   need to add a user to your BizSpark account. Please keep in mind your
>   BizSpark account is limited; all users count toward this limit, even
>   if they are later removed.
>
> - Go to the [Microsoft.com/BizSpark](https://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/) portal and log in with the    Microsoft account assigned to the current administrator.
> - Navigate to the My BizSpark tab
> - Click the Manage link at the right of the page
> - Click manage members tab
> - Add the new member (for example, John Doe)
> - The new member will receive an email invitation, and will have to accept the BizSpark Terms of Service and EULA to proceed.
>
> Once the invitation has been accepted and the new user has received
>   their confirmation of enrollment:
>
> - Go to the [Microsoft.com/BizSpark](https://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/) portal and log in with the Microsoft account assigned to the current administrator.
> - Navigate to the My BizSpark tab
> - Click the Manage link at the right of the page
> - Click manage members tab
> - Click Change Primary Contact, above the list of team members
> - Select the new administrator from the list.
>
> If you are unable to locate the Primary Account holder or they have
>   left the company, please contact [BizSpark support](http://mailto:bizspark@microsoft.com?subject=BizSpark%20Support&body=Thank%20you%20for%20contacting%20BizSpark.%20Please%20provide%20as%20much%20of%20the%20following%20information%20as%20possible,%20as%20it%20will%20help%20expedite%20our%20response%20to%20you.%0AContact%20name:%0AStartup%20name:%0AMicrosoft%20Account/Live%20ID:%0ASpecific%20description%20of%20issue%20experienced%20or%20question:%0A%0AThank%20you,%0A%0AThe%20BizSpark%20Team) to make the
>   necessary changes.

Comment: @shahed-c-msft thanks to your answer... I try to follow steps on official FAQ as you suggest but my page hasn't de option "Manage"

Comment: Hi Rafael, as the FAQ suggests, you may contact BizSpark Support to make the necessary changes if you need help. You can also use the BizSpark Support forum, here: http://trainingsupport.microsoft.com/en-us/tcbizspark

Comment: Yeah, same here.  There's no 'Manage' so these instructions are useless to me.  Tried clicking on the 'Support' link and just got the general Microsoft support with no option to pick 'BizSpark'.